# After using mod_rewrite rules HTML form not setting `$_POST` after submitting

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 simple files `register.php` and `user-insert.php`.

`register.php` file keeping HTML form with method `POST`, submit button have named `submit` in following:

```
<form action="user-insert.php" class="contact-form" method="post">
    <ul>                         
        <li>
            <label for="who-are-you" class="first-col">Who are you?</label>
            <select name="who-are-you" id="who-are-you" class="select">
                <optgroup label="Who are you?">
                    <option value="1">Employer</option>
                    <option value="0">Employee</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email" class="first-col">Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com" required />
        </li>               
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

And there is `user-insert.php` file:

```
session_start(); // tried to remove this, but It do nothing with this problem

// there checking for an errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // do something
} else {
    echo "POST false";
}
```

It always returns me `POST false`. There is no any errors. Only `POST` is not setting.

**Problem**

Problem is with `.htaccess`, if I remove content from this file it starts working. `.htaccess` redirecting now from `www.mysite.com/any-file.php` to `www.mysite.com/any-file/`. Maybe have you ideas what's wrong with it?

`.htaccess` file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:(?:index|(.+))\.php)?\?lang=lt\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.?]+)/?\?lang=lt\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:(?:index|(.+))\.php)?\?lang=(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.?]+)/?\?lang=(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3/%4? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+\.php)\?lang=lt&(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/lt' -> redirect to /en/ or /lt/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)$ $1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=(en|lt)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:en|lt)/)(.+)$ lt/$1 [DPI,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ - [L]

# now all urls have en/ lt/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&id=$3&param=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Any rewrite that triggers a redirect will discard post data. Do you really need to redirect?

Comment: @apokryfos I really need to make urls like `www.mysite.com/etc/something/` instead of `www.mysite.com/etc.php?param=something` with or without redirecting I no care.

Comment: Then set the action to a URL that will not trigger redirecting, e.g. `/user-insert/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect with **302**, not send post data after redirect. You can use **307** as redirect code to redirect with post data.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:(?:index|(.+))\.php)?\?lang=lt\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=307,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.?]+)/?\?lang=lt\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=307,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:(?:index|(.+))\.php)?\?lang=(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1? [R=307,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.?]+)/?\?lang=(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1? [R=307,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3? [R=307,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3/%4? [R=307,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+\.php)\?lang=lt&(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2 [L,NE,R=307]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=307,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=307,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2/ [R=307,L,NE]

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/lt' -> redirect to /en/ or /lt/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)$ $1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=(en|lt)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:en|lt)/)(.+)$ lt/$1 [DPI,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ - [L]

# now all urls have en/ lt/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&id=$3&param=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept the answer.